# How can multiple windows 8 installations exist on 1 system without interfering with each other?

Tags: windows-8, multi-boot

The Windows 8 installation that was supplied with a particular machine is locked with no admin privileges so to enable personalised use of the hardware I need to have a completey separate version of windows 8 installed on a separate drive.

I have tried this 2 ways.
1. Cloning the drive and reseting the password for the admin account on the cloned drive.
2. Doing a fresh install of Windows 8 on the second drive.

Both ways have eventually ended up corrupting data on one or both of the drives, presumably because windows is getting confused between the installs.
At some stage windows will go into automatic recovery which always results in one or both drives becoming corrupted.

It's worth noting that in both methods, each drive ended up with it's own 'System Reserved' partition and presumably, boot loader, as 1. was a disk clone and 2. was installed with the first drive disconnected.

Is there a way to prevent this behaviour or at least tell the installs to completely ignore the other drive, especially when attempting automatic restore?

Comment: How many physical drives do you have? Also, have you tried to partition any of them?

Comment: is resetting the local admin account with external tools an option? not sure if chntpwd works with windows 8, only used it on Win7 and XP personally. it might spare you the hassle of two instances of Win8.

Comment: One simply way is install Windows 7 then install Windows 8 then upgrade the Windows 7 installation to Windows 8

Comment: @Rudolph 2 Physical drives. On the second drive I kept half space free for the possibility of installing a linux/osx partition later.

Comment: @TheUser1024 I've reset the local admin account on the second drive when I cloned it. The first drive needs to remain intact without any hacks or password resets etc.

Answer (score 0):

It used to be that the LILO and GRUB boot loaders which come with various Linux installations could "hide" partitions from other operating systems. Obviously, you don't want to install Linux just for a boot loader but I'm pretty sure that other ones are available which will do the same thing.

With regards to installation of the second copy of Windows 8, you **must** ensure that you do it to a separate drive (not just partition) with all other drives (apart from the DVD drive) disconnected. **THIS IS IMPORTANT!**. If you try to install to a drive which is not the current boot drive the boot partition on the boot drive **WILL** be overwritten.

Once the installation is complete, reconnect any other drives to their previous ports (i.e., if the old boot drive was on SATA connection 1, put it back to connection 1) and boot. From there, install the boot loader app and try it. You may need to set it do map partitions around so that the newly installed copy of Windows thinks it's still on drive C but, hopefully, the app will take care of that for you. If it doesn't work, look at using the supplied MS tools to reset the boot sectors.

I should note that I've not used Windows 8 in any way shape or form but the above is how I would do it if I was using Windows 7

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the help but I fear installing the second drive in this manner is why I'm ending up with problems. I plan now to restore the first drive (via an image) and then install the second copy on the other drive with both drives connected. At least this way windows will attempt to setup it's own boot selector and, I'm hoping, be aware of multiple installs in future and not corrupt things in auto restore.